# Invertible elements of $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle x^{p+1}\rangle$?

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory, finite-fields, abelian-groups

I was asked to show that the group of invertible elements of the ring $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/\langle x^{p+1}\rangle$ is isomorphic to the abelian group $\Bbb{Z}_{p-1}\times\Bbb{Z}_{p^2}\times\left(\Bbb{Z}_p\right)^{p-2}$ and I have no idea to begin the solution. Can any body provide me a way to solve this problem. Thank you in advance for your support.

Here $p$ is a prime.

Comment: Start by noticing that elements invertible in $R=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^{p+1})$ are represented by polynomials of degree $<p+1$ that are not divisible by $x$. If $f\in R$ is not divisible by $x$, then there are polynomials $a,b$ such that $af+bx^{p+1}=1$. In particular $af=1$ in $R$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $\mathbb{Z}_{p-1}\times (\mathbb{Z}_p)^{p}$?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout: This is the given problem. Do you have a good reason to believe the problem statement is wrong?

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout If $g\in\mathbb{F}_p$ is a primitive root of unity, then $(x+g)^{p-1}$ has order $p^2$. In fact, it is different from $1$, $(x+g)^{p(p-1)}=(x^p+g^p)^{p-1}=(p-1)g^{p-2}x^p+1\neq 1$, and $(x+g)^{p^2(p-1)}=g^{p-1}=1$.

Comment: If you look instead at $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$, for rather larger but otherwise arbitrary $n$, you’ll see more clearly what’s going on. It’s an extremely interesting story.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout The coset of $1+x$ has order $p^2$. We have $(1+x)^p=1+x^p\neq 1$, but $(1+x)^{p^2}=(1+x^p)^p=1+x^{p^2}=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, no matter what the base field $k$, an element of $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$ is uniquely writable as $\lambda u$ where $\lambda\in k^\times$, a group of order $p-1$ in our case, and $u\in1+\langle x\rangle$, the group of principal units in this local ring. When you analyse the structure of $1+\mathfrak m=1+\langle x\rangle$, where $\mathfrak m$ is the maximal ideal of this ring, you will have the whole story.